# Data Structure to use instead of hash_map

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, data-structures, hashmap, wchar

I want to make an array containing three wide character arrays such that one of them is the key.

"LPWCH,LPWCH,LPWCH"  was not able to use the greater than/lesser than symbols since it thinks it is a tag

Hash_map only lets me use a pair. wKey and the element associated with it. Is there another data structure that lets me use this?

This set will be updated by different threads almost simultaneously. And thats the reason why I don't want to use a class or another struct to define the remaining two wide character arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LPWCH` as a key and `std::pair<LPWCH, LPWCH>` as an element.

Answer (score 1):

Using any of LP-typedefs is not good. You would only be comparing the points, and not strings.
`LPWCH` is nothing but a `WCHAR*` which can be drilled down to `void*`. When you compare two pointers, you are comparing where they are pointing, and not **what** they are pointing.

You either need to have another comparer attached to your map/hash_map, or use actual string datatype (like `std::string`, `CString`)